# Differential Equation order & degree

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A little confusion on the order and degree of a differential equation .

1. Let $\,r'' = -\dfrac{k}{r^2}\,$ or $\,r^2 \cdot r'' = -k\,$ where $r''$ is with respect to $\,t\,$ (e.g $\,dr/dt\,$).
   Would the order be two because of $r''$? It would not be influenced by the $r^2$ term, right? Would the $r^2$ affect the degree, say, instead of being $1$ due to the $r''$ exponent of $1$, it would be $3$ because of the $1+2=3$, the two being the exponent of $r$ ($r^2$)?
2. $\left. 2 \cdot \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{y^2 – 1}{x} \right.\,$
   Is the degree $2$ because of $y^2$? I originally thought the degree was one since only the highest derivative was considered but maybe not. Here the order should certainly be $1$. Some clarification on this would be appreciated since I have not found these types of examples anywhere online. Thanks!
   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The order of differential equation is defined as the highest number of derivatives of any term involved in the equation.
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation#Equation_order),

> Differential equations are described by their order, determined by the term with highest number of derivatives. An equation containing only single derivatives is a first-order differential equation, an equation containing double derivatives is a second-order differential equation, and so on.

In your first example the highest order derivative term is $r''$, so that the equation is of second order.
In the second example you only have one derivative $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, so its order is $1$.